# What pins can be left floating?

Tags: circuit-design

I'm quite new to electronics, but I'am wondering what pins can be left floating. For example in a MPU-6050 or HC-05 what pins can be left floating and which do i need to wire

Comment: Please edit your question to include links to the datasheets and, if possible, screengrabs of the pinouts.

Comment: since this pretty clearly depends on the individual part, no general answer can be given. As anything else about the function and requirements of a component, you'll have to read the component's *datasheet* to learn which pins can be used how – or can be left floating.

Comment: with datasheets was should i look for in particular?

Comment: Generally the procedure is that you read the datasheet and it will tell you how each and every pin is supposed to be connected, or what to do with them when unused. Do you have a specific question about some pin?

Comment: A very warm welcome to the site. Please note that it's not a free design house, homework-answering service or on-line technical encyclopaedia, copied out to you on demand. People will help you take the next step if your question shows you've already done as much as you possibly could - which yours doesn't, I'm afraid. Please edit your question and greatly improve it. Show your own work and own findings in considerable detail with any schematic. The schematic tool here is easy to use. The better the quality of your question, the better the quality of the answers it will attract. Again, welcome.

Comment: You have to look at the datasheets of HC05 and MPU-6050 in particular.

Answer (score 1):

In general, OUTPUT pins can be left floating if you don't need that function.

INPUT pins *can* be left floating, but they might drift to an intermediate voltage level which would cause the internal circuitry to consume excessive current. This is not damaging, but just wastes current. In addition, if they drive interrupts or other level sensitive functions, then you could get spurious signals. If this is an MCU with configurable pins, you can often program I/O pins as outputs -- thus allowing them to remain floating.

Obviously, the power and ground lines need to be wired up.

If there is a RESET (power-on-reset often), crystal oscillator pins, and other required function pin, then these need to be wired correctly.

Answer (score 1):

It's never a good idea leave input pins floating.

When designing electronics system the experienced designer always look for this kind of problems.

---

Floating input pins may bring the input circuitry of that pin in an unknown state or worst yet in a latch-up state.

Input pins can be left floating if the integrated circuit has an internal pull-down or pull-up resistor.